# How to insert printout of an MP4 file in Microsoft OneNote

Tags: windows, mp4, onenote

Looking for a way to "insert printout" of an MP4 in Microsoft OneNote (which is OneNote speak for embedding a video).

Any ideas how to accomplish this? It would be nice to play the video straight from the OneNote page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include an MP4 file (you can include it as an attachment), but you can include an embedded video from youtube in OneNote via the OneNote API by using POST ~/pages - in the HTML you send, include this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This page will contain a video!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe data-original-src= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h07qZLLQc4I", width="280" height="280"/>
    </body>
</html>
```